# Difference in response between fiddler and jmeter

Tags: jmeter, fiddler

In `jmeter` I get a response as:

```
{"mi_fb_res":[],"error":false,"session_status":true}
```

But in fiddler for the same HTTP request I get

```
{"mi_fb_res**":[{"id":"47","**n":"WI\/d9kc4owq"}],"error":false,"session_status":true}.
```

I need the to extract the value "47" in `jmeter`, how can I do this?

Comment: You didn't really send the same request. What are the full HTTP headers you sent in each case?

Comment: yes EricLaw. I made a mistake. Thanks for the clarification. The problem is solved :)